# Sandbox Paypal payment Checkout using stored card Vault

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I am using Vault to stored credit card information to Paypal sandbox account which is done.

Now i want to integrate the payment process using stored credit card id. please guide how achieve this. Below are code block.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // 
        PaypalCCModel ccmodel = new PaypalCCModel();
        ccmodel.Number = "5555555555554444";  //"4111111111111111"; //"4012888888881881";// "4417119669820331"; // Visa
        ccmodel.ExpireMonth = "11";
        ccmodel.ExpireYear = "2021";
        //ccmodel.cvv2 = "222";
        ccmodel.Type = "MasterCard";

        PaymentViaStoredCard(StoreCreditCardInPaypal(ccmodel));
        return View();
    }

    // It return Vault Credit Card Id 
    private string StoreCreditCardInPaypal(PaypalCCModel ccmodel)
    {
        Address billingAddress = new Address();
        billingAddress.city = "Johnstown";
        billingAddress.country_code = "US";
        billingAddress.line1 = "52 N Main ST";
        billingAddress.postal_code = "43210";
        billingAddress.state = "OH";

        //Creating the CreditCard Object and assigning values
        CreditCard credtCard = new CreditCard();
        credtCard.expire_month = int.Parse(ccmodel.ExpireMonth);
        credtCard.expire_year = int.Parse(ccmodel.ExpireYear);
        credtCard.number = ccmodel.Number;
        credtCard.type = ccmodel.Type.ToLower();
        //credtCard.cvv2 = ccmodel.cvv2;
        credtCard.first_name = "pankaj";
        credtCard.last_name = "Kumar";
        credtCard.billing_address = billingAddress;

        try
        {
            //Getting the API Context to authenticate the call to Paypal Server
            PayPal.Api.APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
            Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            //headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+ apiContext.AccessToken.ToString());
            apiContext.HTTPHeaders = headers;
            // Storing the Credit Card Info in the PayPal Vault Server
            CreditCard createdCreditCard = credtCard.Create(apiContext);

            //Saving the User's Credit Card ID returned by the PayPal
            //You can use this ID for future payments via User's Credit Card
            //SaveCardID(User.Identity.Name, createdCreditCard.id);
            return createdCreditCard.id;
        }
        catch (PayPal.PayPalException ex)
        {
            //Logger.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return "-1";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return "-1";
    }

    public void PaymentViaStoredCard(string CardID)
    {
        // Preparing Item
        Item item = new Item();
        item.name = "Item Name";
        item.currency = "USD";
        item.price = "1";
        item.quantity = "1";
        item.sku = "sku-1123324";

        List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();
        itms.Add(item);
        ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
        itemList.items = itms;

        //Here is the Credit Card detail which we need to use from our database
        CreditCardToken credCardToken = new CreditCardToken();
        //Here, we are assigning the User's Credit Card ID which we saved in Database
        credCardToken.credit_card_id = CardID;

        //Specify Payment Details
        Details details = new Details();
        details.shipping = "1";
        details.subtotal = "1";
        details.tax = "1";

        //Specify the Total Amount
        Amount amnt = new Amount();
        amnt.currency = "USD";
        // Total must be equal to the sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
        amnt.total = "3";
        amnt.details = details;

        //Create Transaction Object
        Transaction tran = new Transaction();
        tran.amount = amnt;
        tran.description = "This is the recurring payment transaction";
        tran.item_list = itemList;

        //Adding the transaction above to the list
        List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
        transactions.Add(tran);

        //Specifying the funding Instrument here.
        //Notice that we are not using any credit card details here
        //But we are using the Credit Card Object which has the Card ID
        FundingInstrument fundInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
        fundInstrument.credit_card_token = credCardToken;

        //Adding the Funding Instrument to the list
        List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new List<FundingInstrument>();
        fundingInstrumentList.Add(fundInstrument);

        //Specify the fundind Instrument List and Payment Method as Credit Card
        //Because we are making the payment using the store Credit Card
        Payer payr = new Payer();
        payr.funding_instruments = fundingInstrumentList;
        payr.payment_method = "credit_card";

        //Finally Making payment Object and filling it with values
        Payment pymnt = new Payment();
        pymnt.intent = "sale";
        pymnt.payer = payr;
        pymnt.transactions = transactions;

        try
        {
            //Getting the API Context to authenticate the Call to Paypal Server
            PayPal.Api.APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();

            // Making the payment using a valid APIContext
            Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
        }
        catch (PayPal.PayPalException ex)
        {
            //Logger.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The  PaymentViaStoredCard method is stored credit card information on PayPal sandbox vault and return vault Card id which is passed to PaymentViaStoredCard method to pay amount PayPal. But I am getting error in PaymentViaStoredCard method like internal server error. 
The full error description is 
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error occurred.","information_link":"developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/…"}

Comment: Your question sounds like it could perhaps be answered by reading the Vault documentation. But if you still need help, I would suggest providing more details about what you implemented.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response Preston. I have updated the code block on above. Please let me know if I am missing anything. I am using PayPal. NET sdk 1.9.1.

Comment: Why are you using those card numbers? They won't work in the PayPal sandbox.  Use random numbers from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator/

Comment: Hi Preston, I appreciate your response.It is working fine as suggested by you to use random generated credit cards. But the requirement in  my web application is to fill credit card details by user and then pay amount using stored Credit Card Id with Paypal Sandbox environment so i can can't use random generated credit cards it will be filled by users. So please suggest how i can achieved this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eh? Users will enter real cards in the live environment, and real cards will work. In the sandbox environment, test with random cards. Not numbers like 4111. This is not complicated.

Comment: Thanks.I am facing one more issue when using same Paypal .NET SDK 1.9.1 with ASP.NET Core 2.2.0. It throw error when creating object of CreditCard credtCard = new CreditCard(); in method StoreCreditCardInPaypal. Error is given below : System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'PayPal.Api.PayPalResource' threw an exception.'
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PayPal.Log.LogConfiguration' threw an exception.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c.

Comment: Some googling about System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager suggests that's related to your .NET linked libraries. I don't have any expertise on this , so you'll probably need to do some research and troubleshooting